# add an horizontal line and some icon with text in bottom like facebook

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-cardview

I want add a footer to a cardview.

my current XML layout in RecyclerView is this:

(this xml code act as row in RecyclerView )

**code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"

        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/placeholder_grey"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/movie_progress"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_margin"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_margin"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:theme="@style/CircularProgress"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/movie_poster"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/poster_thumb_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/poster_thumb_height"/>



    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_round_rect"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/poster_thumb_width"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/poster_thumb_width"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_margin_half">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movie_year"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_margin_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_margin_content"

            android:alpha="0.38"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#f14e4e"
            tools:text="2009 | EN"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movie_title"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_margin_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_margin_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_margin_quarter"
            android:textColor="#9b92b3"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:text="Movie Title"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movie_desc"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_margin_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_margin_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textColor="#9b92b3"
            tools:text="Nowadays, user engagement is considered one of the most important metrics for the success of your app"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Now I want add more thing to this code.

I want add an horizontal line. (I think I must View) and some Icon with text like this picture:

[image]

how can I do that?

Comment: See my answer below. I have added two xmls for your expected design. Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have designed two XML for two different `CardView`. See the attached image for output. Hope this will help you~

**`Facebook like CardView` with `Image`, `Title` and `Some Text`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false" >

    <!-- Content -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="88dp">

        <!-- Thumbnail :: Image-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <!-- Two-Line TextView -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_thumbnail"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="This is a title"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/text_title"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="Here is Some text" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**`Facebook like CardView` with `Image`, `Title`, `Some Text` and `Like`, `Comment`, `Share` actions:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false" >

    <!-- Content -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="88dp">

        <!-- Thumbnail :: Image-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <!-- Two-Line TextView -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_thumbnail"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="This is a title"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/text_title"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#727272"
                android:text="Here is Some text" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Bottom line with actions -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@id/image_thumbnail">

            <!-- Horizontal line -->
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#ababab">

            </View>

            <!-- Like + Comment + Share -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <!-- Like -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_like"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.2"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_like"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="#727272"
                        android:text="Like"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- Comment -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_comment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.6"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_comment"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="#727272"
                        android:text="Comment"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- Share -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_share"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.2"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_share"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="#727272"
                        android:text="Share"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks.you help me a lot. I am noob in android. I googled for days to find an example in web But I couldn't. for web design, You could find a lot of example.

Answer (score 0):

Add a view like this below the cardView

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/black"/>
```

then use LinearLayout/RelativeLayout below it to hold the icons and text

Answer (score 0):

please try this.... hope can help

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:text="Title"/>

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="8dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/some_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:text="some text"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:text="Like"
                    />

            </FrameLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:text="Like"
                    />

            </FrameLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:text="Like"
                    />

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```